# I can't install pandas from cmd on windows 10 , i'm using python 3.9

Tags: pandas, pip, windows-10

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kret5jq\pandas\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kret5jq\pandas\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kret5jq\pandas\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kret5jq\pandas\
    Complete output (101 lines):
    Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 61, in process_pyx
        from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 238, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 234, in main
    find_process_files(root_dir)
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 225, in find_process_files
    process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 191, in process
    processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 66, in process_pyx
    raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py:425: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 450, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 433, in setup_package
    def finalize_options(self):
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 240, in generate_cython
    """Custom distutils command to clean the .so and .pyc files."""
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kret5jq\pandas\setup.py", line 809, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 450, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 433, in setup_package
    def finalize_options(self):
  File "C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-w8b3tt8f\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 240, in generate_cython
    """Custom distutils command to clean the .so and .pyc files."""
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
Cythonizing sources
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Download anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas currently [released wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.25.3/#files) for Python 3.5-3.8. Python 3.9 is not yet released and no wheels are provided for pandas or its dependencies (esp. numpy).

My advice is to install a supported version of Python. Python 3.7 is currently the best, Python 3.8 is a little bit too new. But Python 3.9 is simply not ready yet.

If you insist on using Python 3.9 you have to compile **pandas and all dependencies** from sources. Install [compiler](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), install Cython, etc…